# How to set InsertCommand parameter as function call?

Tags: c#, postgresql, ado.net, postgis, dataadapter

I working on a GIS application which uses the PostgreSQL database with PostGIS extension. I already created the data access logic for entire project and everything works fine except the geometry value insert.

I have to pass geometry value as a function call:

```
INSERT INTO mygeotable (id, name, geom) VALUES 
    (1, "MyName", ST_GeomFromText('POINT(755888.4156 112458.556)', 23700))
```

As you can see I have to call the **ST_GeomFromText** PostGIS function on `INSERT` for the `geom` column value. This `geom` column is a string value from the view of ADO.NET but it can't be set as a text on `INSERT`.

I think ADO.NET automatically formats my `INSERT` command this way:

```
INSERT INTO mygeotable (id, name, geom) VALUES 
    (1, "MyName", "ST_GeomFromText('POINT(755888.4156 112458.556)', 23700)")
```

Which is wrong because of quotation marks!

How can I set `INSERT` command's `geom` parameter to use `ST_GeomFromText` function call?

I use parameters for every column. InsertCommand CommandText is:

```
INSERT INTO mygeotable (id, name, geom) VALUES (id, name, geom)
```

The geom paramter DbType is String. There is no DbType for function call!

Comment: I use parameters for every column. InsertCommand CommandText is: INSERT INTO mygeotable (id, name, geom) VALUES (id, name, geom). The geom paramter DbType is String. There is no DbType for function call!

Answer (score 1):

Pass the parameters to the function as numbers in instead of passing the whole function call:

```
INSERT INTO mygeotable (id, name, geom) VALUES
    (id, name, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(X Y)', Z))
```

BTW double quotes like in `"MyName"` do not make valid strings as they are reserved for identifiers. Strings should be wrapped by single quotes.

Comment: You right! The double quotes are invalid, I just typed here fast. So the problem is when I set value: row["geom"] = "ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1, 2)', 23700)" and then call adapter.Update(table) it throws an "invalid gemoetry" exception which means the insert command text was wrong, since from sql pane I can run the same query without error.

Comment: If you want to pass numeric `X` and `Y` values to make a point, use `ST_MakePoint(X, Y)` instead. Also, you may need to wrap this in `ST_SetSRID(geom, 23700)` to set the SRID. [More info here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24486/how-to-insert-a-point-into-postgis/24487#24487)